# Change application theme using eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I cannot change my application theme. I tried going to

> /res/values/styles.xml

and changed resource AppBaseTheme to `android:Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar`. I reinstalled the application and tried but it still had the light theme with the action bar.

How can I change the app's theme or at least the theme for each activity individually?

Comment: See docs: [Apply a theme to an Activity or application](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme).

Comment: I'm following the docs. It says <application android:theme="@style/AppTheme" > points to AppTheme and I modified AppTheme. I could input the theme directly in there but it seems to me the correct way would be to do it from styles.

Comment: have you tried clean and rebuild the whole application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that in each activity you didn't refer to the specific `style.xml` file in which you applied the custom theme.

But as MH said in the comments section, refer to the Android Dev Site: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme

As for applying themes to activities look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

(They have to be declared in the manifest)

[image: Look here]

*If you would provide code I believe your problem can be pinpointed.*

Comment: Thanks I entered the theme directly on the manifest and it worked. So the problem is the styles somehow not being referenced in the manifest or something like that. I have no idea why though since that part is built automatically by the sdk.

Answer (score 0):

When using Eclipse to create a project, you have a v11 styles.xml and v14 styles.xml.

AppBaseTheme actually inherits from one of those, not the "normal" styles.xml where you were looking.